# Are there any seforim that explain taamey halocho?

Tags: jewish-books

Are there any seforim that explain the reasons why we do halochos.
I find halocho very dry and want to find the pnimius in understanding them.

Comment: Mabey sefer hachinuch

Comment: Not mitzvos, halochos

Comment: Likkutei Halachos of Rabbi Nosson of Breslov?

Comment: Note, the penimius of all halachos are they are Hashem's ratzon, and are therefore beyond reason. To use lashon benei adam, they are what He prefers, and are insights into who He is (Rambam explains in Moreh Nevuchim that Hashem and His Ratzon are identical), and are therefore our way of getting to know Him, and emulate Him. Tanya is a good starting place to being this line of thought. I also recommend this shiur: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yj_PSfT1IBM. I say this because I had the same question as you, and I found the ta'amei mitzvot, while beautiful, didn't help, and sometimes hindered.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend [Peninei Halakha](https://ph.yhb.org.il/en/about-2/), by [R' Eliezer Melamed](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eliezer_Melamed), for this purpose. R' Melamed's detailed discussion of the practical details of each section of Halacha is integrated with a discussion of the spiritual roots of those laws, including both Torah and Rabbinic laws.

For examples of his extensive treatment of the meanings behind Halacha, see;

- Chapter 1 of his book on *Pesah*, ["The Meaning of the Holidays"](https://ph.yhb.org.il/en/category/pesah/01-the-meaning-of-the-holiday/)
- Chapter 1 of his book on *Women's Prayer*, ["Fundamentals of the Laws of Prayer"](https://ph.yhb.org.il/en/category/03/03-01/)

Answer (score 0):

It's not an easy read, but you would be hard pressed to find a book that addresses this issue more thoroughly than [Shaar HaMitzvot](https://seforimcenter.com/Etz-Chaim---Shaar-6--Shaar-HaMitzvot-Ahavat-Shalom-Edition__p-10131.aspx) by Rabbi Chaim Vital.

Comment: Of course, @mbloch.  I will try to edit in a few examples before Shabbat, bli neder. Thank you for your advice on improving this answer